# Widgets in Android onload method()?

Tags: android

Is there any onload() method or something after you attach a widget on the screen to pop up something else inAndroid?

Answer (score 0):

That's essentially what the [onEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onEnabled%28android.content.Context%29) method does.

Comment: well, I tried just system.out.println(" ") it works, means it is showing on LogCat, but is it possible to open a new activity from this method onEnabled (Context contex)

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you think someone has answered your question adequetely, click the check to accept the answer and or vote up the response. If you have another question. Please create a new question to ask and answer.

Comment: Please ask that in a new question.